# GLFW Window Takes a while to open

Tags: glfw

The GLFW window takes about 1 second to open is there anyway to shorten it?

```
std::cout << glfwGetTime() << '\n';
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED,0);//removes window borders for next created window
GLFWwindow * mainwindow = glfwCreateWindow(600,400,"FreemanGL",0,0);
std::cout << glfwGetTime();
```

First timer is less than 0.009 seconds, second is approx 1.05 seconds.

Comment: Well I did something (I have no idea what, I looked everywhere for what I had done (switched to orginal libraries, cleared most file with the solution (the ones generated when building a project))) but the time is now down to 0.25 seconds (although I don't notice much of a difference in startup time tbh) to open the window. It is defiantly the window that is delaying, not GLFW initializing. I think its either windows fault or GLFW passing non-optimal parameters to windows. Anyway I am happy with my applications startup time now...